# Use Airplay Mirroring and Airplay Speakers at the same time on iPhone

Tags: ipad, appletv, airplay

Is it possible to use AirPlay mirroring for the video output and AirPlay speakers for audio at the same time? Unfortunately, the AirPlay menu available in the dock only allows me to select one device at a time.

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to display the video signal on the Apple TV and listen to the video's audio track on the Bose speaker.

Comment: What kind of video is it? Game or just video from iTunes library?

Comment: It's a video from iTunes.. Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iTunes content you may use Apple's [Remote app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8) to send signal to multiple sources at once.

For local content for [Apple TV 2nd and 3rd generation on latest firmware](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4448?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) you might try sending AirPlay stream to AppleTV and then choose your Airplay enabled speaker for sound output in AirPlay Preferences on AppleTV itself. It will only work for 2.0 (Stereo) sound.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Does the 'local content' version work with Bluetooth speakers? I think it does not :(..

Comment: Did you try it? As I remember AirPlay would list A2DP enabled speakers alongside other receiving devices. I'm not sure if it's working on AppleTV though.

Comment: I'll give it another try... :)

Comment: You should remember that Bluetooth range is much smaller than WiFi. It's usually about 10 meters or less.